# What's up with old volumes of the Journal of Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: soft-question, journals

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for MO, but I'm certain that some people visiting MO must have been confronted with the same issue as mine.

It happened several times that a reference cited in a paper I'm reading has been published in the Journal of Algebraic Geometry around the 90's or early 2000's. However, looking up for the title of said reference turns out no results. I can only find other papers citing the same reference, but not the reference itself. And for sure, when I visit the journal's webpage, for some reason the oldest available issue is volume 11 from 2002. There is no mention whatsoever of earlier volumes, which must however have existed before at some point in time.

For instance, an explicit example is Pappas' "On the arithmetic moduli schemes of PEL Shimura varieties" which was published in the volume 9, issue 3 of the Journal of Algebraic Geometry. However, there is seemingly no trace of the published version online.

Would somebody know more about this?

Comment: I don't know about this particular journal but to me this is not strange. In 2002, lots of journals were still only available on paper. Many journals have put older volumes online but certainly not all of them.

Comment: I've had the problem as well. If you have access to a university library, the librarian will help you get a copy of it. @HjalmarRosengren The issue, at least por this particular journal, is that often there isn't even an online record of the article in the journal's website, let alone the PDF.

Comment: FWIW, that paper is indexed by [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1752014) and [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/0978.14023), so I don't agree that it "turns out no results". Just (as mentioned above) that there is likely no online version available.

Comment: for searches such as this, [WorldCat](https://search.worldcat.org/title/journal-of-algebraic-geometry/oclc/23703491) will tell you how and where to find old issues of a journal.

Comment: I can confirm that I  have an article in JAG from the previous century, and they only sent me paper reprints of it, no pdf.  They only went digital in 2002, and they don't seem to have digitized back issues unfortunately. So I guess one has look those up the old way.

Comment: (Also the AMS is the  current publisher of the JAG, but I don't think they were the original ones. I suspect -- and this only guess-- the AMS doesn't have the rights to digitize the old issues.)

Comment: Thank you all for your insights! As a young researcher, I may have been taking for granted the idea that every resource has by now a digitalized version. I should have asked more precisely how come the older volumes are not retroactively digitalized yet. Donu Arapura suggests an interesting point about publication rights. Instead, my question currently sounds like "Volumes were there, and woosh! they disappeared", hehe... ! As R. van Dobben de Bruyn raised it, they didn't even disappear per se, as precise indexation is available (certainly so for most papers published in these older volumes).